# Ask for a value till valid input provided (maybe using do-while loop)

Tags: c#, do-while

I have this bit of code:

```
string yourName;
        do { yourName = Console.ReadLine(); }
        while (!yourName.All(Char.IsLetter));
```

After checking for letters, I want to output "Please Enter a Valid Name." If the string does contain numbers.

Is it possible to do within a do-while loop?
If not, can you suggest any solution?

Edit: Solved. I used a while loop instead:

```
string yourName;
yourName = Console.ReadLine();
while (!yourName.All(Char.IsLetter))
        {
            Console.Write("Please Enter a Valid Name: ");
            yourName = Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: It's probably _possible_ with do-while loops, but I would use a while loop for this.

Comment: As @Sweeper said it is normally done with `while(!validInput){...}` loop as shown in duplicates I picked. Indeed if you must use `do-while` you should first check your assignment notes (and previous chapters)... than probably use flag that tell whether to show retry message or initial input message before asking for text.